# Why does Adobe Analytics call fail to fire even though DTM Switch shows the Satellite call?

Tags: adobe-analytics, adobe-dtm

I'm trying to attach a DTM Event Based Rule to a Social Share button from [Add This](http://www.addthis.com), and it's not working.

I have other rules on the same page which are working fine, so I'm confident all the setup basics are correct.

In fact it almost works... In the log below... why does DTM Switch report `event13` but then it doesn't show up in the *Adobe Analytics Server Call*?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Still not fully clear why it partially works (as opposed to not working at all), but the problem seems to be caused by attempting to bind Event Based Rules to elements that were injected into the DOM via Javascript (such as the AddThis API).

Solved by using a custom event handler to dispatch a Direct Call Rule:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {    
    onElementInserted("body", '.at-share-btn', function(element) {
        $(element).one('click', function() {
            var network = $($(this).find('title')[0]).text();
            window.digitalData.event.socialNetwork = network;
            _satellite.track('social-network');
            return true;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

where `onElementInserted()` is borrowed from [jquery detecting div of certain class has been added to DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415400/jquery-detecting-div-of-certain-class-has-been-added-to-dom)

Answer (score 0):

Is it an s.tl() beacon? Is event13 set in custom code? I'd doublecheck that s.linkTrackEvents is set to allow event13- see [Omniture events is not firing/sending data via DTM when using s.tl tracking methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609400/omniture-events-is-not-firing-sending-data-via-dtm-when-using-s-tl-tracking-meth) for more info on that.

Comment: event13 is set through the DTM UI (no custom code).